# Multiples of a given irrational number can be arbitrarily close to a natural number

Tags: real-analysis

How do I prove the following:

For every irrational number $q$, given $\varepsilon>0$, there exist natural numbers $N$ and $M$ such that $|Nq-M|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 6):

Hint: Look at the fractional parts of $q,2q, 3q, \dots $. There are an infinite of them squeezed into $(0,1)$.

Comment: How does this prove the question? For example: all of the fractional parts might lie in (0.1,0.9)

Comment: @Agile_Eagle: $nq=n(\lfloor q\rfloor+\{q\})$, ergo $\{nq\}=\{n\{q\}\}$. If $\{q\}=\overline{0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots}$ is irrational, you can get any possible value in $(0,1)$ as a fractional part of $nq$ for some $n=10^k$. They cannot all lie in $(0.1,0.9)$, because, say a multiple has fractional part $0.10001$, then multiplying it by $9$, we get a multiple with fractional part $0.90009\gt 0.9$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a small variant:

Consider the quotient ${\Bbb R}/{\Bbb Z}$ which can be identified to the circle $S^1$. The irrationality of $q$ is equivalent to the injectivity of the quotient map $\pi:{\Bbb R}\rightarrow S^1$ restricted to ${\Bbb Z}q$. The assertion amounts to prove that for any open neighborhood $V\ni0$ in $S^1$ there is always a $n\bar{q}\in V$ with $n\neq0$, i.e.
$\pi({\Bbb Z}q)\cap(V\setminus(0))\neq\emptyset$

Consider the translates $V_n=n\bar{q}+V\subset S^1$ for $n\in{\Bbb Z}$ (still open, of course). If you can find an $m\in{\Bbb Z}$ such that there exists $n\bar{q}\in V_m\setminus(m\bar{q})$ then $(n-m)\bar{q}\in V\setminus(0)$ and you are done.

If not, it means that for all $m\in{\Bbb Z}$, $\pi({\Bbb Z}q)\cap V_m=\{m\bar{q}\}$. But this says that $\pi({\Bbb Z}q)$ is discrete in $S^1$ and since $S^1$ is compact, this is in contradiction with its infinitness.

Answer (score 0):

Not to toot my own horn or anything, but my answer to this question

[Can we make $\tan(x)$ arbitrarily close to an integer when $x\in \mathbb{Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/can-we-make-tanx-arbitrarily-close-to-an-integer-when-x-in-mathbbz/24041#24041)

includes an outline of how you would prove this (similar to Moron's hint).