# Bound on the approximation of a number on the unit interval by the positive multiples of an irrational number

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, irrational-numbers

Suppose that I am given an irrational $\alpha$, then the set
$$\{\{n\alpha\}:n\in \mathbb N\}$$

with $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is dense in $[0,1]$ (see [1]).

Now given $\epsilon>0$ and some target number $0<p<1$, I would like to find an upper bound on $n\in\mathbb N$ that verifies $$\left|p-\{n\alpha\}\right|<\epsilon$$

Any ideas appreciated. There are many related questions. For instance:

[1] [Density of positive multiples of an irrational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624387/density-of-positive-multiples-of-an-irrational-number)

[2] [Multiples of a given irrational number can be arbitrarily close to a natural number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24806/multiples-of-a-given-irrational-number-can-be-arbitrarily-close-to-a-natural-num)

[3] [Dense set in the unit circle- reference needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569152/dense-set-in-the-unit-circle-reference-needed)

Comment: S'pose $p$ is near $1$, and $\alpha$ is really tiny. Then $n$ will have to be enormous, on the order of $1/\alpha$. Your big-oh has to allow for dependence on $\alpha$, doesn't it?

Comment: indeed, what I conjecture more precisely is $\mathcal O(f(\alpha)\log(1/\epsilon)$, but with the big O notation as a function of epsilon the function on $\alpha$ is just a prefactor. Of course, I might be wrong.

Comment: You'd also have to let it depend on $p$. Given $N$, the points $\{n\alpha\}$ for $1 \leqslant n \leqslant N$ partition the unit interval into $N+1$ intervals, the longest of which must be longer than $\frac{1}{N+1}$, so there is a $p \in (0,1)$ whose distance to the nearest point $\{n\alpha\}$, $n \leqslant N$, is larger than $\frac{1}{2(N+1)}$. Hence the supremum over all $p$ is at least $\frac{1}{2\epsilon} - 1$. For fixed $p$ you may get a smaller bound, but I don't think $O(\log 1/\epsilon)$ is realistic.

Comment: @DanielFischer, fair enough, thanks for the comment, I will remove the conjecture from the question statement. Maybe you can rephrase the comment into an answer?